# In Java FX, how can Text be drawn starting from the top left (instead of bottom left)?

Tags: java, javafx

Using Java FX, text x and y coordinates refer to the bottom left corner of the text. How can you make the coordinates refer to the top left corner?
For example, if text is drawn at the origin (0,0) it draws off screen but in this case, we want it displayed at the top left.

```
public class JavaFxOriginText extends Application  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 100, 50, Color.WHITE);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
            Text text = new Text(0, i*10, "Hello World! " + i);
            text.setFill(Color.BLACK);
            root.getChildren().add(text);
        }
    }
}
```

This code snippet shows
[image]

But "Hello World! 0" is missing from the display.

Comment: The coordinate system already originates in the top-left corner. What makes you think otherwise?  Also, wouldn't you be better off using a `VBox` for this layout? Your "Hello World! 0" text is not showing because 0,0 is hidden under the title bar...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the [text origin](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/text/Text.html#setTextOrigin(javafx.geometry.VPos)) to [`VPos.TOP`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/geometry/VPos.html#TOP) (default is `VPos.BASELINE`):

```
Text text = new text(15, 0, "The Thirty-Nine Steps");
text.setTextOrigin(VPos.TOP);
```

> Defines the origin of text coordinate system in local coordinates.

You might also wish to set the [text bounds type](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/text/Text.html#setBoundsType(javafx.scene.text.TextBoundsType)) to [`TextBoundsType.VISUAL`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/text/TextBoundsType.html#VISUAL) (default is `TextBoundsType.LOGICAL`):

```
text.setBoundsType(TextBoundsType.VISUAL);
```

> The geometry of text can be measured either in terms of the bounds of the particular text to be rendered - visual bounds, or as properties of the font and the characters to be rendered - logical bounds. Visual bounds are more useful for positioning text as graphics, and for obtaining tight enclosing bounds around the text.

Comment: Thanks! The correct method call is 'setTextOrigin'.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Slaw & @Zephyr.

Just an alternate thought, if the OP is more concerned about drawing/positioning the text (i.e, not always vertically), then the main issue is using Group as root node.
Without disturbing your drawing, if you wrap the Group in a Stackpane, i believe you will get the desired behavior.

```
public class JavaFxOriginText extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Group root = new Group();
        StackPane mainRoot = new StackPane(root);
        mainRoot.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);
        Scene scene = new Scene(mainRoot, 100, 50, Color.WHITE);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Text text = new Text(0, i * 10, "Hello World! " + i);
            text.setFill(Color.BLACK);
            root.getChildren().add(text);
        }
    }
}
```